# Adding execute for specific users and groups on folders and remove it from files

Tags: centos, permissions

I'm trying to execute this command but it does not get the expected results

```
chmod -R u-x+Xrw,g-x+Xrw,o-x+Xr *
```

I want all my directories to be executable, and all my files to NOT be, this is for a storage folder of a web server where I dont want anyone executing anything. just read and write, but i want it's directories to be traversable.

For some reason, the files end up being executable too, what am I doing wrong?.

**EDIT**: I know how to solve the problem with solutions shown in other answers, however i would like to know why the command as written here keeps the x flag on files when it seems it would remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want different permissions for files (read & write) vs directories (read & execute), I'd recommend using two separate commands instead of trying to combine them into one. The wildcard `*` will match files and directories.

Secondly, the `X` permission adds "execute" ...

> if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user

... so if the file started off with any (user, group, or other) execute permission, then it will end up with executable permissions.

Consider two separate commands:

```
find /base/path -type d -exec chmod u+rx,g+rx,o+rx {} +
```

and

```
find /base/path -type f -exec chmod u-x+rw,g-x+rw,o=r {} +
```

Adjust the permission sets according to your own policies; the above commands:

- on directories: *add* read & execute for everyone
- on files: *removes* execute for user and group
- on files: *adds* read & write for user and group
- on files: *sets* other to only read

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!. the behaviour of X is not well explained in most places.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of testing, I've found that the following chmod command should give you the expected behaviour:

```
chmod -R ugo-x+Xr,ug+w FILE
```

For example, let's start with a directory and file with 775 permissions:

```
[root@testvm1 ~]# ls -ld testdir/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root 22 Dec 14 16:47 testdir/
[root@testvm1 ~]# ls -l testdir/testfile
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 0 Dec 14 16:47 testdir/testfile
```

And now we run the command:

```
[root@testvm1 ~]# chmod -R --verbose ugo-x+Xr,ug+w testdir/
mode of ‘testdir/’ retained as 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
mode of ‘testdir/testfile’ changed from 0775 (rwxrwxr-x) to 0664 (rw-rw-r--)
```

The directory has retained its execute permission, while the file has been stripped of its execute permission.

Assuming that you want 775 permissions for all directories and 664 permissions for all files, you can use the following variant that manipulates the write permission as well:

```
chmod -R ugo-wx+Xr,ug+w *
```

---

The original `chmod` command in the question does not strip the execute permissions from the file. This difference in behaviour seems to be result of how the modes are evaluated. `chmod mode1, mode2 file` provides the same result as `chmod mode1 file; chmod mode2 file`. Since the user permissions are evaluated first in the original command, an execute permission at the group/other categories will result in the file retaining execute permissions. An example is shown below:

```
[root@testvm1 testdir]# chmod 775 testfile

[root@testvm1 testdir]# chmod -R --verbose u-x+Xrw,g-x+Xrw,o-x+Xr testfile
mode of ‘testfile’ retained as 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)

[root@testvm1 testdir]# chmod -R --verbose u-x+Xrw testfile
mode of ‘testfile’ retained as 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
[root@testvm1 testdir]# chmod -R --verbose g-x+Xrw testfile
mode of ‘testfile’ retained as 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
[root@testvm1 testdir]# chmod -R --verbose o-x+Xr testfile
mode of ‘testfile’ retained as 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
```

Note that directories automatically get the execute bit with `X`, so this behaviour only affects the files.